# retreive array value from text file and post it in array python

Tags: python, numpy, text

hello First i'm new on python
What i want is to retreive from text file that containts set of array values :

This is my text files:

```
[0 1]   
[1 0] 
[1 1] 
[0 1] ....
```

i want to get an array that contains only the axes one

```
[[1],[0],[1],[1]]
```

and transofrm it to a vector :

```
 [ 1,0,1,1]
```

i did this code and it does not work

```
file = open('Score.txt','r')
for i in file:
    y_true = np.argmax(i, axis=1).transpose()
    print(y_true)
```

Comment: What is your intended output?

Comment: @rognajosh i  want to get a vector that contains [ 1,0,1,1]

Comment: @roganjosh i edited my question

Comment: So there really isn't any argmax functionality needed, you just want the second column?

Comment: @roganjosh yes i want the second column and transform it to a vector  [ 1,0,1,1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I'd get the second axis as a list, then you can do whatever you want with it. Assuming your example is the format for all data

```
with open(r"Score.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
res = [int(x.split()[1].replace("]","")) for x in lines]

>>> res
[1, 0, 1, 1]
```

Comment: You could also use `ast.literal_eval` to create the list object on each row and index it

Comment: I am not really familiar with that module, wouldn't that require the items in the lists to be comma separated? Just asking..

Comment: Actually, that's a completely valid point. Yes, it would fail because numpy is an extension to Python.